# CSS background left aligned on a centered text

Tags: css, background, centering

I have a vertical menu in which each item is **centered**.
This is done with ul/li.

I would like to have a **repeatable background image** for each item, which is all aligned on the left, but aligned with inside text width on the right.

Here is an illustration of what I want to do :
[illustration as an image](http://neo7.fr/css-problem.jpg)

Of course, it is possible to add DIVs to the HTML structure.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome. please always post the relevant CSS + HTML to your question

Comment: it would be good if you provide working example in fiddle

Comment: I'm unsure of if this is possible using only CSS

Comment: Need a bit of JavaScript for this. Don't think it is possible with CSS alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with span and a pseudo-element

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/HsJof)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"> /* not required */
  <ul>
    <li class="center"><span>Some Long Text</span></li>
    <li class="center"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li class="center"><span>Text</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* THE GOOD STUFF */ 

li{
  overflow:hidden; /* hides all extra pixels */
  font-size:2em;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom:.5em;
}

.center {
  text-align:center;
}

li > span {
  diaplay:inline-block;
  background:red; 
  position:relative;
  padding-right:0.5em;
}

li.center > span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right:100%;
  top: 0;
  height:100%; 
  width:2000px; /* some really large number*/
  background:red;
  margin-right:0; /* or remove and add padding-right to span */
}
```

Comment: That sure as hell is an awesome answer!! I bow to thee!!

Comment: True but you didn't mention that as a requirement.

Comment: I wasn't blaming you :), it was just a note for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be possible alone with CSS. So I went ahead and created this with jQuery.

HTML is

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="center">Text</span></li>
    <li><span class="center">Text big</span></li>
    <li><span class="center">Text small</span></li>
</ul>
```

All I do in script is this.

```
$('li .center').each(function() {
    var width = $(this).width();
    $(this).css({"paddingLeft": (200 - width)/2 + 'px'});
});
```

I have added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FMtn3/) for reference.

I hope you won't have trouble adding a background image instead of #666 for `.center`